# F-Test vs Independent Samples T-Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test

If I have two samples from different populations and I would like to know if there is enough evidence to conclude that some particular relation. Ex. The IQ level is affected by the amount of fluoride in water. So I take a sample from a pop. where the fluoride is high and one from a pop. where the fluoride is low. 
Which test should I use to conclude, given a particular significance level,  whether there is enough evidence to conclude that the high content of fluoride affects children IQ or not?

I was thinking of Independent Samples T-Test because it tells me if these differences could've occurred by random chance or not.

Answer (score 1):

T-test is appropriate, if you believe that your distributions are normal (which is likely the case). Otherwise you could use a non-parametric alternative, such as Mann-Whitney U-test.

F-test is a generalization of t-test to multiple samples, so you don't need it here.

Finally, t-test may only tell you that the two samples are different, but it can never prove the opposite. So if your p-value is higher than the significance level, you will need to use something like TOST equivalence test, to prove that the difference between the two samples is less than some specified value.

Comment: Thanks, but in order to use the t-test the variances have to be equal. So, I have to use the f-test to test whether the variances are equal or not and then if they are equal I would have to use the t-test. Am I right?

Comment: There is a version of t-test for unequal sample variances: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

Comment: The OP asks for a causal relationship "*The IQ level is affected by the amount of fluoride in water*"; a t-test won't establish that. There are a number of important issues that come in here, but even if we were not looking at causality, consider [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted_variable_bias).

Comment: T-test or its equivalent is appropriate here for showing that the two populations are different. This will not prove that this difference comes from fluoride. This is not a problem of testing but of the experiment design.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion in this thread about what is meant by *F test*.  There are *F* tests for purposes that are quite different.  Probably the one students encounter most is the *F* test used for the omnibus hypothesis test in anova.  (Referenced by Vadim ).  But there is also an *F* test used to test if the variances of two samples are equal.  (Referenced by @YadielVelez ).  As a general principle, it's important to specify the statistical test being used.  Terms like *F test*, *t test*, and *chi-square test* are immensely ambiguous, and are likely to result in confusion.

Answer (score 0):

While an independent samples t-test will test the null that "the two populations have equal mean IQ" it won't do what you want.

No matter what test you do, you can't reach the conclusion that you seem to want to reach: That fluoride has a causal relationship with IQ, certainly not with this design.  You have an observational study and can't make causal conclusions from it.

But you could vastly improve your design. If you are going to the trouble of giving IQ tests to all these people (and an IQ test takes considerable resources, including at least an hour of each participant's time and additional time for the psychologist to score the test) then you could at least get a bunch of demographic variables to help control for them.

Also, rather than a "high" and "low" fluoride group, it would probably be better to use a range of fluoride levels. Then you could include fluoride level along with the control variables in a regression.

However, *before* doing all this (which would cost tens of thousands of dollars) you should do a thorough literature review. Fluoride and IQ have been studied before. A quick Google search found over a million hits and even a search in Google Scholar found over 30,000.